# Improper Integral which should diverge

Tags: integration, limits, logarithms, improper-integrals, absolute-value

Consider

$$\int_{-2}^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{x} = \left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-2}^{0-\epsilon} + \int_{0+\epsilon}^1\right) \frac{\text{d}x}{x} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (\ln|-\epsilon| - \ln|-2| + \ln|1| - \ln|0 + \epsilon|$$

And this is

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ln|-\epsilon| - \ln(2) - \ln|\epsilon| = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ln\bigg|\frac{-\epsilon}{\epsilon}\bigg| - \ln(2) = -\ln(2)$$

Instead it diverges. Why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: You should use two different viariables in order to calculate the two integrals, for example $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$, otherwise you are just obtaining the Cauchy principal value that can be a real number even though the integral is divergent.

Comment: You can only split up the integral into two integrals if both of them converge. Or at least you have to prepare yourself for the result to be nonsensical if you do it anyway.

Comment: @Meowdog, not necessarily. If the integrand function were $\frac1{|x|}$, you could split up the integral in two integrals and you would get the right answer that is $+\infty$

Comment: @Angelo Okay, i agree with you in some cases. But you can not show convergence that way, only divergence.

Comment: @Meowdog, obviously in that way we can only show divergence.

Comment: @Angelo Could I use the same variable but with saying that the integral converges iff the two separate limits do converge both? Like instead of what I wrote above, writing this:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ln|-\epsilon| - \ln|-2| + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} - \ln|\epsilon|$$

and then say: those limits are separate, they do not separately converge, hence the integral does not converge

Comment: You could say that by calculating the two limits, you get $+\infty-\infty$ which is an indeterminate form, hence that integral does not exist. But if you had got $+\infty+\infty$, you could say that the integral diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Isn't "diverge" used both for when a limit does not exist and for when it's infinite? Or at least this is what I used to see...

Comment: @Numb3rs, yes “diverges” is used in both cases, that is why I have distinguished the two cases (does not exist vs infinite).

Comment: @Angelo Oh, ok! Thank you! Another question: if I had

$$\in_0^1 \frac{dx}{\ln(x)}$$, would the right split be

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} + \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}$$?

Comment: No, it would be just the first integral. You should not write the second one.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, in order for this integral to converge we require separate limits to converge, i.e.
$$
\int_{-2}^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{x} = \left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-2}^{-\epsilon} + \lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\int_{\delta}^1\right) \frac{\text{d}x}{x}.
$$
Since the individual limits to not converge the integral diverges.

What you have discovered is an example of the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) (CPV), which is a technique of singular integral regularization, in which a finite value can be assigned to certain divergent integrals.

We note that the CPV is just one way we can regularize this integral since
$$
\int_{-2}^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{x} ``=" \left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-2}^{-3\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^1\right) \frac{\text{d}x}{x} = \log(3/2)
$$
also provides a regularized value that is different than the CPV.  What makes the CPV seem intuitively correct is that it assigns a value of zero to divergent integrals of odd functions on a symmetric interval of integration. For example
$$
\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}=0,
$$
which seems like the only sensible value you could assign to this integral.

Furthermore, the CPV is just a special case of a family of singular integral regularizations.  For poles of $n=2$ one may use [Hadamard regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization) and in general, integrands containing poles of arbitrary integer order can be regularized via the finite part integral described by Charles Fox [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/generalization-of-the-cauchy-principal-value/34E58E1057169989D3CCCD0BCD76B0DE).

**Edit:**

The [Analytic Principal Value](https://quant-math.org/wp/2016/05/05/the-analytic-principal-value-by-way-of-the-cauchy-plemelj-fox-theorem/) is another interpretation of Fox's regularization which amounts to integrating around a pole by deforming the path of integration into the upper/lower complex plane.

Comment: That was so interesting!